# Validate route parameters in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a method like this in my `UserController`:

```
public function verifyUsername()
{
    $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|max:30|unique:users,username'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => 'false',
            'errors' => $validator->messages()
        ), 400);
    }
    else
    {
        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => 'true'
        ));
    }
}
```

I want to have a URL route like this:

```
/users/verify/username/{username}
```

How can I pass the `username` variable from the route to the method in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

You pass in a array with `uses` set to the `ControllerName@methodName`

You might want to look at [Named Routes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes) for more information.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('users/verify/username/{username}', 
           array('uses' => 'UserController@verifyUsername'));
```

**Controller**

```
public function verifyUsername($username)
{
    //it would be nice if this works, but I don't think it will
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::get('username'), $rules);

    // something like this should work
    $data = ['username' => $username];
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
}
```

Comment: How do I pass `$username` to the validator?

Comment: Updated per your comments.

Comment: I tested Validator::make($data, $rules); and it doesn't work (